# VS shortcuts - create block

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

VS2010 or later - is there a way to 'block' a block, put it in a `{}`?

None shortcut-key references I've met seem to mention this (nor have I found it in the menus, to tell the truth), but it seems to be something trivial.

Alternatively - can I create such a thing myself (macro?)?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486/how-do-i-make-visual-studio-auto-generate-braces-for-a-function-block), especially the answer about defining a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# you can create your own snippet similar to ones that shows up when you chose "surround with" from right click menu (Ctrl+K,S) like "do" for "forr".

Snippet location for "do" - ...\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\do.snippet

Your snippet would probably look like

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[do
{
  $selected$ $end$
}]]>
</Code>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6hf704tz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to surround code with Ifs or Trys you can assign these to keys.