# shortcut for creating braces in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut, braces

many of time I have a if condition with just one line, like this:

```
if (true)
    // my single code
```

but sometimes, I want to expend my if condition to 2 or more codes, so I should use braces.

```
if (true)
{ 
    //do something
}
```

I want to know is there any shortcut for change first code to second one?

Comment: Generally it is considered good practice to always use braces, even if you only have one line of code controlled by the if statement. Skipping braces in this case might cause unexpected errors, for example if you comment out that line of code, the if statement will be controlling the next one...

Comment: not a shortcut for braces ,but if you try to type `if` and then press `tab` twice, curly braces is auto-created. Try it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486/how-do-i-make-visual-studio-auto-generate-braces-for-a-function-block

Comment: No shortcut I know of. But I remember with project Roslyn (new customizable compiler) I have seen a code provide / issue provider created in a demo on build that adreses exactly this. But unfortunately this has to get released yet unless you're willing install Roslyn and do this on your own.

Comment: Thanks @Niang I know about that, but my answer is not this exactly.

Comment: Type just 3(three) characters: i, f, <tab> ==> It becomes "if (true) { }" with focus on 'true'. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a code snippet that surrounds the selected text like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>curls</Title>
      <Description>Puts curly braces around the selected text.</Description>
      <Author>Erik Venema</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[{
                $selected$
                $end$
                }]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Save it as curls.snippet and import it in the code snippet manager.

After that you can use the snippet by selecting the text, press `CTRL-K`+`CTRL-S` and select the curls snippet.